# styled-system | Resolve theme style function within component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, styled-system

I'm trying to figure out how to resolve a styled-system function within a component by default. The idea is to have a container element which uses the theme out of the box to supply the main responsive breaks.

Right now what I am doing below is supplying the styled-system `width` function with an object like this:

```
//theme.js
const CONTAINERS = {
  xs: "100%",
  sm: "55rem",
  md: "74rem",
  lg: "100rem",
  xl: "131rem",
};
export default {
 containers: CONTAINERS,
//other items
}
```

```
//Container.js
export default (props) => {
  const { containers, grid } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  return (
    <Container px={grid.margin} width={containers} {...props}>
      {props.children}
    </Container>
  );
};

const Container = styled("div")(
  css`
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
  `,
  compose
);
```

This DOES work, however, it's not as clean as I would like it.
I would love to be able to simply have

```
const Container = styled("div")(
  css`
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    ${//maybe resolve the responsive widths here}
  `,
  compose //<- a group of styled-system functions supplied in one object
  //or resolve responsive widths here
);

export default Container
```

This would be so much cleaner as I could then combine and export layout components into one file
without having to do the `const Container...` + `const StyledContainer...` formalities.

I'm toying with the idea of writing a function which loops the `containers` object and returns the widths wrapped in media queries but I'm wondering if styled-system does this out of the box?

Comment: Not sure if this is precisely the api you are looking for, but this https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-theme-get might help, as it allows for using the theme (including responsive breakpoints) inside the styled string (no need to `css` either, as its inferred).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find anything in the docs to make something like this work out of the box so I've implemented it manually.

```
//theme.js
const BREAKPOINTS = {
  xs: "0em",
  sm: "37em",
  md: "48em",
  lg: "64.625em",
  xl: "84em",
};

const CONTAINERS = {
  xs: "100%",
  sm: "55rem",
  md: "74rem",
  lg: "100rem",
  xl: "131rem",
};
```

The script below takes the objects above and puts the breakpoints values into a wrapping `@media` then inserts the values of the containers as `width:` inside of that. Then returns the entire lot as css.

```
const Container = styled("div")(
  css`
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;

    &::after,
    &::before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      min-height: 2rem;
      height: 4vw;
      max-height: 6rem;
    }
  `,
  compose,
  (props) => {
    const breakpoints = props.theme.breakpoints;
    const containers = props.theme.containers;

    const makeMedia = (media) => {
      return (...args) => css`
        @media ${media} {
          ${css(...args)}
        }
      `;
    };

    const getMedia = Object.keys(breakpoints).reduce((media, breakpoint) => {
      const breakpointWidth = breakpoints[breakpoint];
      media[breakpoint] = makeMedia(
        [breakpoint !== 0 && `(min-width: ${breakpointWidth})`]
          .filter(Boolean)
          .join(" and ")
      );
      return media;
    }, {});

    return css`
      ${Object.keys(breakpoints).map(
        (key) => containers[key] && getMedia[key]`width: ${containers[key]}`
      )};
    `;
  }
);
```